# Reuse of AJAX result between different pages

Tags: php, ajax

I am developing a PHP based web application.
I am using same AJAX call on many pages of my web application. Result of this AJAX call is used to populate select options about 10-15 in number. How can I avoid AJAX call while moving between pages and reuse the same result between multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose any of two different methods:

1) Server side,  which I have used in old apps,  not the best fit for mobile apps, but works fine if your users get connected from a desktop, like corporate users.

By server side I mean using server sessions,  In PHP you call them by this way:

```
Session_start();
```

at the beginning of your PHP script,  and than you can store the AJAX collected data and even user collected data in one or many sessions.  Keep in mind that each session is a PHP array, so you can use multidimensional collection of data.

```
$_Session['AjaxData']['id']='55345Af7';
$_Session['AjaxData']['Name']='John Doe';
$_Session['AjaxData']['Role']='Admin';
```

2) The second approach is modern,  indeed targeted to mobile users.  This approach is to store temporary data in LocalStorage browsers API,  either as session or either as objects.

Localstorage API has up to 5Mb,  but for a bunch of reasons,  please count on no more than 2.5 MB.  To save data on local storage, you should use a javascript function that pushes each item to an array, then convert to JSON and save it to the API.

```
 function addItemToStorage () {
     storageArray.push(item);
 }
 LocalStorage['ajaxData']=JSON.stringify(storageArray);
```

And to read it,  on other page,  you need to use the getTtem method save in to a variable and manipulate as you need:

```
var AjaxData=LocalStorage.getItem('ajaxData');
```

For sure any of theese methods should work for you.

I strongly recommend not to rely on w3schools as a source of knowledge or coding examples.  Mostly outdated and not well supported, if you want to do a great job, stay away of it,  rely of better sources like [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Finally don't store temporary data on cookies unless it is useful for the moment when your visitors return,  like shopping carts, user names, part of user credentials, not all credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps immensely.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'how to cache some data on clients machine' then look towards *localstorage*

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Yes. I am using XHTML and NOT HTML5.

Comment: @bvnbhati First, XHTML has basically been abandoned for years. Second, you can use localStorage with an XHTML doctype just fine. It's a JavaScript thing supported in all common browsers.